# \mkdatezeros deprecated error - biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, overleaf

I'm using LaTeX through overleaf, and if I include the year in my bibliography, the following error shows up:

```
Package biblatex Warning: '\mkdatezeros' is deprecated. Please use 
'\mkyearzeros', '\mkmonthzeros' or '\mkdayzeros' as appropriate. 
Falling back to '\mkmonthzeros'.
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, so any help is really appreciated. This is my bibliography file.

```
@article{inductionfirst,
author = {Vacca, G.},
journaltitle = {Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society},
number = {2},
pages = {70--73},
publisher = {American Mathematical Society},
title = {Maurolycus, the first discoverer of the principle of mathematical induction},
url = {https://projecteuclid.org:443/euclid.bams/1183420503},
volume = {16},
date = {1909}
}

@incollection{sep-recursive-functions,
    author       =  {Odifreddi, Piergiorgio and Cooper, S. Barry},
    title        =  {Recursive Functions},
    booktitle    =  {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
    editor       =  {Edward N. Zalta},
    url =   {https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/win2016/entries/recursive-functions/},
    date         =  {2016},
    edition      =  {Winter 2016},
    publisher    =  {Metaphysics Research Lab, Stanford University}
}
```

This is the bibliography chunk of my main file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=mla,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

Comment: `biblatex-mla`  uses the deprecated macro. You aren't doing anything wrong. You could report it to the package maintainer. Or you could wait and assume it will get fixed, then report if not. The warning is not really directed at you in the first instance, but at the maintainer of the style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most intents and purposes the warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: '\mkdatezeros' is deprecated.
(biblatex)                Please use '\mkyearzeros', '\mkmonthzeros' or
(biblatex)                '\mkdayzeros' as appropriate. 
(biblatex)                Falling back to '\mkmonthzeros'.
```

is not something to worry about. `biblatex-mla` sets `datezeros=false` and with that setting the definition of all of these macros is the same. That means that it is not urgent to fix this warning; the behaviour will be as before.

In any case a warning like this is directed at the package maintainer and not so much at the user as [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) points out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515318/mkdatezeros-deprecated-error-biblatex#comment1303007_515318). Still this is something that should be brought to the maintainer's attention. So I reported the issue at https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/issues/21.

If you want to get rid of the warnings now, you can add the following to your preamble

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

Or you could load `babel` with the `american` language, because for some reason the `american` localisation module of `biblatex-mla` does not use `\mkdatezeros` at all.